# UILabels not displaying NSAtrributedStrings with custom fonts set in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uilabel, xcode6, nsattributedstring

When I set a custom font on a plain UILabel using Interface Builder everything works fine. 
It shows up on IB, simulator, and device correctly.

**When I make a UILabel attributed, it displays the custom font correctly in IB but it doesn't work in the simulator or on the device. It just returns to the default system font.**

**I've heard other people have this problem. Has anyone found a solution?**

Notes:

- My work around has been to just use plain labels, and update programmatically.
- My fonts are loaded properly because it works if create the label programmatically and it works with plain UILabels.
- Found this in xCode 6 and xCode 6.1 beta, targeting iOS 8

Comment: This bug also persist in Xcode 7.0.